# Control Flow in decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I am having trouble in understanding the flow of control in a Python program having a decorator.

```
def executor(func):
    def innerExecutor():
        #print("inside executor")
        print("------------------------")
        func()
        print("------------------------")
    return innerExecutor

@executor
def multiply():
    n1 = 10
    n2 = 20
    print("multiplication = ", (n1 * n2))

multiply()
```

What trouble I am having with is: When the `executor()` function is called, and it returns the reference of `innerExecutor()`, where is this reference stored? When is the control actually passed to the inner function? I am very new in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax

```
@some_decorator
def somefunc():
   ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
somefunc = some_decorator(somefunc)
```

This is possible in Python because functions are [first-class objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). They can be passed as arguments to, and returned from, other functions - so-called [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

In your example, the final call to `multiply()` actually runs `innerExector()`, a function created by the decorated definition of `multiply()`. To understand what's going on here, take a closer look at the definition of `executor`:

```
def executor(func):
    def innerExecutor():
        #print("inside executor")
        print("------------------------")
        func()
        print("------------------------")
    return innerExecutor
```

When the code:

```
@executor
def multiply():
    ...
```

is run, the function `executor` is called with the function `multiply` as its argument. `executor` defines the function `innerExecutor()`, and returns it, *but does not execute it*. This instance of `innerExecutor()` is called in place of all future references to `multiply()`.

But wait - usually, we don't want to completely replace the function being decorated. `innerExecutor()` needs to call the decorated function at some point. Recall that a decorated function definition:

```
@executor
def multiply():
    ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
def multiply():
    ...
multiply = executor(multiply)
```

Passing the function to be decorated as an argument to the decorator, allows the definition of `innerExecutor()` to call it. But wait - `innerExecutor()` isn't called until much later, after `executor()` has returned and it's argument `func` has gone out of scope. So why does it work?

Thanks to another feature of Python called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). What this means is the inner function can refer to local variables defined in the enclosing scope - including arguments passed into the outer function `executor` - *even after exiting the enclosing scope*. The magical thing about closures is that the interpreter detects the dependency of the inner function definition on a local variable of the outer function, and keeps it available even after `executor()` returns. This [link](http://www.trytoprogram.com/python-programming/python-closures/#introduction) goes into more detail about closures.

Finally, the call to `multiply()` in the last line actually calls the instance of `innerExecutor()` that was created when the decorated definition was run, which in turn calls the original  undecorated version of `multiply()`.

Every time a decorator is used to decorate a function definition, it creates a new instance of the inner function, which replaces the undecorated function. So if you decorate 5 different functions, 5 different instances of `innerExecutor()` are created. Later, when any of those decorated functions are called, it will instead call instead the appropriate instance of `innerExecutor()`, which in turn calls the corresponding undecorated function.

Answer (score 0):

> it returns the reference of innerExecutor(), where is this reference stored?
>
> When is the control actually passed to the inner function?

It is not stored in anywhere, it is called as below:

```
innerExecutor(multiply)
```

That's why your decorator method needs to return its own reference, otherwise, it would be equivalent to this:

```
None(multiply)  # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

[Here's the documentation of aboves behavior](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax)